# Многопоточность в java, почему порядок вывода результата разнится?

Tags: java, многопоточность, synchronized

Допустим есть такой код. Его результат: ***[Синхронизация] [в Java] [полезная]***. Если объект `Caller` запускать без отдельного потока (т.е. без `extends Thread` и без метода `start()`), то результат будет в другом порядке: **[Синхронизация] [полезная] [в Java]**. Почему так происходит? Прошу дать развернутый ответ.

```java
class CallMe {
    void call(String msg) {
        System.out.print("[" + msg );
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("]");
    }
}
```

```java
class Caller extends Thread {
    String msg;
    CallMe target;

    Caller(CallMe target, String msg) {
        this.target = target;
        this.msg = msg;
        start();
    }

    public void run() {
        synchronized (target) {
            target.call(msg);
        }
    }
}
```

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CallMe callMe = new CallMe();
        new Caller(callMe, "Синхронизация");
        new Caller(callMe, "в Java");
        new Caller(callMe, " полезная");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Поставьте задержку на 200 миллисекунд в методе `run()`, а в методе `main()` добавьте цикл операций на 100 - получите еще больше вариантов.

Потому что невозможно предсказать какой поток войдет в блок `synchronized` первым, даже если вы их запускаете последовательно.

Для синхронизации потоков используются классы

- Semaphore
- CountDownLatch
- CyclicBarrier
- Lock

у них различные цели и методы. Это зависит от конкретной задачи.

---

**Semaphore** - как правило служит для ограничения количества потоков при работе с ресурсами. Доступ ограничивается с помощью счетчика, если его значение больше нуля, то доступ потоку разрешается, а значение счетчика уменьшается. Если счетчик равен нулю, то текущий поток блокируется, пока другой поток не освободит ресурс. Для получения доступа используется метод `acquire()`, для освобождения – `release()`.

```
public class SemaphoreDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Semaphore smp = new Semaphore(2);
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            final int w = i;
            new Thread(() -> {
                try {
                    System.out.println("Поток" + w + " перед семафором");
                    smp.acquire();
                    System.out.println("Поток" + w + " получил доступ к ресурсу");
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    System.out.println("Поток" + w + " освободил ресурс");
                    smp.release();
                }
            }).start();
        }
    }
}
```

Результат работы:

```
Поток 0 перед семафором
Поток 0 получил доступ к ресурсу
Поток 2 перед семафором
Поток 2 получил доступ к ресурсу
Поток 1 перед семафором
Поток 4 перед семафором
Поток 3 перед семафором
Поток 2 освободил ресурс
Поток 1 получил доступ к ресурсу
Поток 0 освободил ресурс
Поток 4 получил доступ к ресурсу
Поток 4 освободил ресурс
Поток 1 освободил ресурс
Поток 3 получил доступ к ресурсу
Поток 3 освободил ресурс
```

Одновременно семафор могут захватить(с помощью метода `acquire()`) только два потока, остальные потоки становятся в очередь, пока один из потоков не освободит семафор методом `release()`.

---

**CountDownLatch** - Позволяет потоку ожидать до тех пор, пока не завершится определенное количество операций, выполняющихся в других потоках, в режим ожидания поток заходит с помощью метода `await()`. Количество требуемых операций задается при создании объекта, после чего уменьшается при вызове метода `countDown()`. Как только счетчик доходит до 0, ожидающий поток разблокируется.

```
public class SimpleCDL {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // задаем кол-во потоков
        final int THREADS_COUNT = 6;
        // задаем значение счетчика
        final CountDownLatch cdl = new CountDownLatch(THREADS_COUNT);
        System.out.println("Начинаем");
        for (int i = 0; i < THREADS_COUNT; i++) {
            final int w = i;
            new Thread(() -> {
                try {
                    // считаем что выполнение задачи занимает ~1 сек
                    Thread.sleep(500 + (int)(500 * Math.random()));
                    // как только задача выполнена, уменьшаем счетчик
                    cdl.countDown();
                    System.out.println("Поток #" + w + " - готов");
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }).start();
        }
        try {
            // ждем пока счетчик не сбросится в ноль, пока это не
            // произойдет, будем стоять на этой строке
            cdl.await();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // как только все потоки выполнили свои задачи - пишем сообщение
        System.out.println("Работа завершена");
    }
}
```

Результат работы:

```
Начинаем
Поток #1 - готов
Поток #0 - готов
Поток #3 - готов
Поток #2 - готов
Поток #4 - готов
Поток #5 - готов
Работа завершена
```

Основной поток создает 6 потоков и ждет пока каждый из этих потоков закончит приготовление к работе.

---

**CyclicBarrier** - используется для синхронизации заданного количества потоков в одной точке. При вызове метода `await()` поток блокируется. Как только заданное количество потоков заблокировалось, с них одновременно снимается блокировка.

```
public class BarrierExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CyclicBarrier cb = new CyclicBarrier(3);
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            final int w = i;
            new Thread(() -> {
                try {
                    System.out.println("Поток " + w + " готовится");
                    Thread.sleep(100 + (int) (3000 * Math.random()));
                    System.out.println("Поток " + w + " готов");
                    cb.await();
                    System.out.println("Поток " + w + " запустился");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }).start();
        }
    }
}
```

Результат работы:

```
Поток 0 готовится
Поток 1 готовится
Поток 2 готовится
Поток 2 готов
Поток 0 готов
Поток 1 готов
Поток 1 запустился
Поток 2 запустился
Поток 0 запустился
```

Несмотря на то, что какие-то потоки закончили подготовку раньше, какие-то позже, стартовали они в одно и то же время, так как блокировка снимается одновременно.

---

**Lock** - Интерфейс. Представляет собой продвинутый механизм синхронизации потоков, который предоставляет большую гибкость чем блоки синхронизации. Поскольку `Lock` это интерфейс, для работы с ним необходимо создать объект одной из его реализаций.

```
Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
lock.lock();
lock.unlock();
```

В начале создается объект типа `Lock`, после чего у этого объекта вызывается метод `lock()` и он захватывается. Попытка другого потока вызвать у этого же объекта метод `lock()` приведет к блокировке этого потока, пока поток удерживающий объект типа `Lock` не освободит его с помощью метода `unlock()`. После вызова метода `unlock()` объект типа `Lock` освобождается, и другие потоки могут его захватить
Основные отличия между `Lock` и синхронизированными блоками:

- Синхронизированные блоки не гарантируют сохранность порядка обращения потоков к критической секции;
- Выйти из синхронизированного блока по времени ожидания(timeout) не получится;
- Синхронизированные блоки должны полностью содержаться в одном методе, в то время как `Lock` может быть захвачен в одном методе, а освобожден в другом.