# Почему join не останавливает 2 поток?

Tags: java, многопоточность

Не совсем понял работу метода `join();` у класса `Thread`.
Есть 2 потока: у первого вызывается метод join, но второй отказывается ждать его. Почему?

```java
public class Thrd {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        MyThread myThread = new MyThread();
        MyThread1 myThread1 = new MyThread1();

        myThread.start();
        myThread1.start();

        myThread.join();
    }
}
```

вот 1 поток

```java
class MyThread extends Thread {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                System.out.println(i + "  potok 0");
                Thread.sleep(10);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MyThread.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

а вот и 2 ой

```java
class MyThread1 extends Thread {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                System.out.println(i + "  potok 1");
                Thread.sleep(10);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MyThread.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Второй поток и не должен ждать первый. Ждать будет главный поток, вызвавший эти 2 потока и затем вызвавший метод [`join()`](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/lang/Thread.java#l1303). Из документации:

> Waits for this thread to die.

а под капотом у метода [`join(0)`](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/lang/Thread.java#l1243) цикл:

```java
while (isAlive()) {
    wait(0);
}
```

т. е. вызывающий поток ждет вызванный. Никакие другие потоки в расчет не берутся.

---

См. [Многопоточность в java, почему порядок вывода результата разнится?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/754845)